# Git commits showing up in log but not in Github

Tags: git, github

I set up a repo in Github and then tied it to my local repository with git init, git remote add origin, etc. I edited some files, made a few commits, and pushed everything with git push -u origin master. This all worked fine. However, commits are showing up with git log but not in my github account. The local repo is set to the correct origin.

I'm using https protocol, and for a few commits I had user.name is the config settings wrong (just put first name instead of first and last) but the email was always correct. Thoughts?

Comment: Try do a fetch from remote, and check commit log.     1:  git fetch origin master     2:  git checkout FETCH_HEAD       3: git log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same issue, even though I have been using this repo with this remote for a long time and I haven't changed anything lately. I supposed that it has something to do with Github's recent brake-down and slowdown, and indeed, they have confirmed it on their Twitter account: https://twitter.com/githubstatus/status/717464295454470145

> Our systems are working through a queue backlog. In the meantime, new
>   pushes may take some time to show on http://GitHub.com .

Hopefully the commits will appear on Github soon :)

Comment: Yes that was totally the issue, all of my commits are showing up now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just slow.  I'm having similar issue with git desktop, branch history shows file changes as well as merged status stating source and destination are the same but in github the branch is still identical to the master and wasn't reflecting the merge from the client. (talking very small kb's here). Twenty minutes later, everything online is caught up.